# cant unwrap lowpoly mesh

Tags: uv

Long story short : Im making a lowpoly mesh for game ready asset thing.

The guys who does this said i should remove any unnecessary loops. However removing some loops makes my unwrap wrong. I'm not finding a way without such loops.

Is it possible to make this unwrap without these loops ?

[image: The loops they said to remove]

[image: Without them]

Answer (score 1):

They are not loops anymore. You can check that by pressing Alt+Shiht+Click.

[image]

You would have to reconnect the corners (Snap these vertices to edge and Merge by distance or Merge (M) by Last) ...

[image]

And then select those edges and Delete (X) Disolve edges.

[image]

But I would rather keep these loops because of very spiky shape of face.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You mean ctrl alt click ?

Comment: Ok let me explain again.

Without those loops my uv gets terrible. As the 2 image shows.

I needed to remove those loops because its a lowpoly and make the uv right again. 

Got it ?

Comment: And btw, i did what you showed, but when re unwrapping it gets wrong. Should i not unwrap after adding these tris ?

Comment: unwrapping it again without the loops would get the same issue. And yes i did apply all transformers...

Comment: can you attach your blend into your Q via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com? You have to select all and unwrap, because by this transforming topology new faces are generated. When I tried on this model texture is fine ...

Comment: Maybe it didnt work for me because i was using angle based method on my unwraps. I chose this conform method and it works great now.

Comment: Probably two notes, in your second screen is a slightly shifted left down corner ov uvmap, but it does not explains your issue, second - usually game industry doesn't like ngons, that is why I merge some vertices, but like now I destroyed inset (frame) around a hole. Does frame around the hole a purpose so should be preserved?

Comment: Im using triangulate so it wont have ngons on the end of the day. >:]

Comment: I was using angle based as well ... hm, ok doesn't matter if you solved it :) BTW be careful with automatic triangulation, sometimes it can be a problem when normals shading comes to play a game :)

Comment: Blender today is giving me some troubling shits huh... Im counting on my normal maps to fix any auto smooth problems.